# FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version" using ai in bot

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, artificial-intelligence, aiogram

I'm making a bot for Telegram with recommendation system in it. There's a part of code:

```
    search_word = str(message.text)
    movie_search = movies[movies['title'].str.contains(search_word)]
    user_movie_matrix['movieId'], movie_search = user_movie_matrix['movieId'].align(movie_search, axis=0, copy=False)
    movie_id = user_movie_matrix[user_movie_matrix['movieId'].eq(movie_search)].index[0]
```

However, I'm getting this warning:

```
FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version. Do `left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)` before e.g. `left == right`
movie_id = user_movie_matrix[user_movie_matrix['movieId'].eq(movie_search)].index[0]
```

Even if I change axis from 0 to 1, it'll get me this:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

I tried also to swap places, but it ended up with one of two errors. Not writing `user_movie_matrix['movieId'], movie_search = user_movie_matrix['movieId'].align(movie_search, axis=0, copy=False)` also gaves first error.

Comment: Thanks, but after adding I've got "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5W7IrMHhqo1LiWMP4j2_RAmQNJ3kNf5/view?usp=share_link
Here it is. At least, he give me same result, but without warnings: predictions for different movies are the same. That is the file that is made after some operations in code. Source file is a MovieLens Dataset (full)

Comment: It has four columns: userId, movieId, rating and timestamp, which was dropped. Movie dataset: movieId, titles, genres (dropped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this warning because you're comparing the Series `user_movie_matrix['movieId']` with the DataFrame `movie_search`. You can remove the warning by specifying the relevant column of `movie_search`:

```
movie_ids = user_movie_matrix[user_movie_matrix['movieId'].eq(movie_search['movieId'])]
```

However, since the comparison occurs element-wise, you'd probably prefer to use `isin`:

```
movie_ids = user_movie_matrix[user_movie_matrix['movieId'].isin(movie_search['movieId'])]
```

(changing variable name since it is likely to return multiple rows)